# Разделение числа на разряды через запятые

Tags: c#

Я написал вполне хороший быстрый код:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace OneProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double num = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("N0", new CultureInfo("en-us")));
        }
    }
}
```

Всё бы хорошо, но если ввести число, которое больше, чем UInt64 (в условии число не больше 10^100), то выходит
[image: Не то, что нужно]

Можно ли это побороть без циклов и т.п.?

Вот вся задача: http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/mod/statements/view.php?chapterid=1599

Comment: Вам придется использовать [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Забыл указать, что число на тестах может быть чуть меньше 10^100 (гугола)

Comment: BigInteger вам прекрасно подойдёт, в отличие от любых примитивных типов

Comment: Прочитать как строчку и просто выводить с конца вставляя после каждого третьего знака запятую.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Пытался через for, но в итоге получается, например, `1,7482397489297E+79`

Comment: Да при чем тут `UInt64.Max`! BigInteger может представлять любые числа.

Comment: Либо, как предлагают выше реализуйте свой аналог, в простейшем случае это может быть просто строка. Ну это, конечно, если вам нужен только вывод и не нужна поддержка операций над числами

Comment: @АндрейNOP ... Я тупой))) Понял, но у меня не объявляется `BigInteger`

Comment: @Osid он в  System.Numerics.dll, не добавлен в references по умолчанию

Comment: Подключите сборку System.Numerics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте к проекту Reference на System.Numerics и воспользуйтесь стандартным `BigInteger`

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Numerics;

namespace OneProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger num = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("N0", new CultureInfo("en-us")));
        }
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

Answer (score 3):

Делаем через строки

```
string bign = "11212131342354364364656121";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bign.Length * 4 / 3);
int jj = bign.Length % 3;

sb.Append(bign[0]);
for(int i = 1; i < bign.Length; i++) {
    if(i % 3 == jj) {
        sb.Append(",");
    }
    sb.Append(bign[i]); 
}
```

Тестируем тут - https://ideone.com/FDTl5Q

Да, и добавлю что в ответе я демонстрирую идею работы со строчками, и сделать так что бы решение проходило все тесты это ваша задача.

Comment: Можно чуть оптимизировать, если указать в конструкторе `capacity`: `bign.Length * 4 / 3`

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, сейчас добавлю